Arguments `target` and `output` must have the same rank (ndim)
i'm working with a multioutput tensorflow model, just for learning purposes, that should output 1 numerical and 1 categorical data (6 classes).
everything seems to be fine, well-defined, but when i fit the model it errors saying "ValueError: Arguments target and output must have the same rank (ndim). Received: target.shape=(None,), output.shape=(None, 6)"
for simplicity, on output layers I have:
layers.Dense(1, activation='relu', name="output_numerical")(x)
layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax', name="output_categorical")(x)

model is compiled as:
losses = {'output_numerical': 'mse', 'output_categorical': 'categorical_crossentropy'}
loss_weights = {'output_numerical': 1.0, 'output_categorical': 1.0}
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses, loss_weights=loss_weights)

and finally, a sample of features x and labels y:
input_numerical | input_categorical
1.0 | 1
1.1 | 0
1.2 | 3
1.5 | 5
....

output_numerical| output_categorical
2.0 | 5
1.1 | 4
3.2 | 3
4.5 | 2
....

Can anyone help me to fix the problem?
I expect that softmax outputs just 1 number, the expected category, but I suspect that is outputing the probs for each class.

Take a look at sparse categorical crossentropy. This can deal with label-encoded targets. Maybe you have to also  reshape your labels to have an additional axis, as they should have shape (None, 1).

It´s important know how what shape has your data
exist Categorical_crossentropy for (vector int)
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/categorical_crossentropy
[[1,2,3],[0,1,0]]
and Sparce_categorical_crossentropy data
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy (number clases)
[[0,0,1,2]]

Please summarize the main contents of the reference links you posted so that in case the links stop working the answer doesn't become useless

The issue is mainly with data mismatch. Try to keep your input layer like this layers.InputLayer(shape=(None,)) and before the output layer try to summarize your model and see how the output shapes are progressing after each layer. In the final output layer, use the number of classes and sigmoid. To get the exact shape. try to add the GlobalAveragePooling1D() layer to collapse the size to avoid this issue. For example:
layers.InputLayer(shape=(None,)),
layers.Dense(512, activation="relu"),
layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="sigmoid")

This is just an example, try to analyse your model using model.summary(), you will see the output shape after each layer. Also, don't forget to check your datasets.
